# difference between .contains() and .keySet.exists() in Scala Maps

Tags: scala, hashmap, contains, exists

I have a map `var surfaceMap = Map[Surface, Array[Event]]()` in Scala where `Surface` class represents geometrical surfaces consisting of planes. In Surface class I define `equals` method as follows:

```
final override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = other match {
    case that: Surface => (planes.deep == that.planes.deep) 
    case _ => false
}
final override def hashCode: Int = planes.##
```

The equality checks if all the planes that construct the surface has the same coordinates. I have a surfaceMap of 8 elements and when I want to add an `Event` to a surface that is already in the map, when I check the existence of the key with `surfaceMap.contains(newSurface)` it returns false but when I use `surfaceMap.exists(_._1 ==  newSurface)` or `surfaceMap.keySet.exists(_ == newSurface)` it takes longer and returns true. I thought `.contains()` and `.keySet.exists()` do the same job but it seems that they are different but I don't understand the difference. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Map.keySet.exists` does not do the same thing as `Map.contains`, `Map.keySet.contains` does.

The difference is that `.contains` uses object's hash code (provided, we are using the default, HashMap, implementation) to quickly navigate to the key you are looking for. This is a constant time (`O(1)`) operation.

`.exists` cannot do that, because it is looking for an arbitrary condition, not an exact object. So, it has to scan the entire set and evaluate the condition for each element, until it finds the one that matches. This is a linear time (`O(N)`) operation.

As to why `Map.contains` returns false in your case, that must be because your `hashCode` implementation is incorrect: you are using the default .`##`, which will be different for different instances, even if they contain the same values (unless, it is a case class).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I modified the hashCode function so that it returns the same number for surfaces that have the same geometry but Map.contains() still returns false. For example, the hashCode of the first 6 elements are : -704080298
-646351565
741598496
-56047142
398825871
398825871 but when I add 6th element contains() returns false even though the hashCode of the 5th and 6th elements are the same

Comment: If it returns false, then either hash codes are different, or `equals` returns false.

Comment: @VahidB, you probably should roll out a real [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want get a better answer.